# kernel is 5.19.0-38-generic but apt install linux-headers-generic says linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (5.15.0.58.56)

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 22.04, linux-headers

I don't know how the, recently installed, 22.04 has got in this mess but assume that a repository I added to get something in the last week caused this as I'm clearly booting into a 5.19.0-38 kernel but the kernel headers for that are not present. (I know because VirtualBox stopped working and is complaining, clearly correctly, that the vboxdrv module is not present.)  The output from `/sbin/vboconfig` is:

```
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic
```

But `apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic` (as root and after `apt update`) says:

```
root@Clevo2:/home/chris# apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic' has no installation candidate
```

I suspect that my grub settings *might* be the problem.  `update-grub` gives me this:

```
root@Clevo2:/home/chris# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-58-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

I haven't rebooted the machine since running that though as I would rather see what advice I get here first.  Can anyone see a way forward?  I am in moderately urgent need of virtualbox (sadly in order to get back to be able to use M$oft Wurd: apologies!)

TIA,

Chris

#### output added 16.iv.2023

```
root@Clevo2:/home/chris# apt-cache policy linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic
linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

#### Contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` added 16.iv.2023:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230223)]/ jammy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
root@Clevo2:/home/chris#
```

I think that says that updates are requested.

Comment: Are you using the hwe packages to get the 5.19 kernel?   Please add to your question the output of apt-cache policy linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic   It should be found in jammy-updates

Comment: Thanks ubfan1.  Output added.  I have used linux for decades but came to Ubuntu from Debian some five years ago and feel I've lost track with modern Ubuntu/Linux.  Are you saying I should have jammy-updates in my repositories. I don't see it in "Software & Updates" but I'm not sure I understand the "Updates" tab there.  The text "jammy-updates" doesn't seem to be be in /etc/apt/sources.list or /etc/apt/sources.list.d anywhere.  TIA!

Comment: From your question. has got in this mess but assume that a repository I added to get something in the last week caused this  After saying this you should have included what this is referring to in the question. We can not guess what you do or add.

Comment: Under the Software & Updates/Updates tab, under the "subscribe to" field, ensure either "all updates" or the "security and recommended" are selected. Then the -updates should be put into your sources.list. Try installing linux-generic-hwe-22.04 to get the 5.19, and maybe the linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 if they are not pulled in with the other hwe packages.

Comment: David5: I wasn't asking you to guess, I was giving you background and some sense of my competencies and lack thereof.  I have made no changes to the repositories since making this report.

Comment: @Ubfan1: thanks again.  I have added contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.  I think it suggests that updates are requested. Software & Updates has "Subscribed to: All updates" in the Update tab.  `apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` installed the linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 package.  That feels like key progress but `rcvboxdrv setup` still says
"This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel"
Do I need to reboot to get things back in alignment?

Comment: A reboot should get you to a 5.19 kernel, with the matching headers. The build-essential package may be needed for building kernel modules.

Comment: Thanks again @ubfan1.  Sadly, reboot hasn't changed things.  `apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` gets me:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic-hwe-22.04 is already the newest version (5.15.0.58.56).
But `uname -all` says 
Linux Clevo2 5.19.0-38-generic #39~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 17 21:16:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
So I seem stuck with some bizarre inconsistency in the packages.  Any thoughts about what to do next?

Comment: Maybe the  Installation and Upgrades Forum https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=333 would be a better place for this back and forth. You should be able to follow the dependency chain from apt-cache depends linux-generic-hwe-22.04 all the way down to apt-cache depends linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 and finally: Depends: linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic.  Don't know what the 5.15 is doing in hwe.

Comment: Hey @cpsyctc, were you able to solve this?

Comment: Not yet sadly and I can't get onto ubuntuforums.org without creating a new account there, waiting for forum management to clarify what's going on there. Do you have similar issue?  Do you have suggestions?!  Very best, C

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this may not be an answer that will work on all machines but it worked on mine where this started. It came from Peter Pont of Laptopswithlinux who supplied the machine:

> Open terminal and run:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt autoremove -y
> ```
>
> Then restart the laptop.
>
> Install this driver via Software & Updates:
>
> NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-525
>
> Restart the laptop
>
> Open terminal then run:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04c linux-tools-oem-22.04c -y
> ```
>
> Restart the laptop and check again.

It was that last install of `linux-oem-22.04c` and `linux-tools-oem-22.04c` that I hadn't done before though I had tried that nvidia driver. I hope this is useful to someone else some day and thanks to all who responded.